# Cypress get text value from an element

Tags: string, text, cypress

I am trying to get a text from an element with Cypress in the first test from the first domain and then type it in the second test in another domain, here is a code
[image]

I have to grab code from h4.

I implemented next part of code:

```
get studentCouponValue() {
    return cy.get('h4').then(($span) => {
        const couponValue = $span.text();
        cy.log(couponValue);
    })
}
```

in logs, I see the correct coupon's value, but when I am trying to type it into the field I get an error

The chain approach doesn't fit my expectation, cause i am going to use it in different tests.

Answer (score 1):

i resolved

```
initStudentCouponValue() {
   const self = this;
    return cy.get('main > .container-fluid').find('h4').then((span) => {
        self.couponValue = span.text();
        cy.log('First log '+ self.couponValue);
        return new Cypress.Promise((resolve) => {
            return resolve(self.couponValue);
        });
    });
}

getStudentCouponValue() {
    return this.couponValue;
}
```

in the test where we want to use value

```
let couponValue;

 admin.initStudentCouponValue().then(() => {
        couponValue = admin.getStudentCouponValue()
    });
```

and later we can use

> coupoValue

for inputs

Update 05.31.23

There are better solutions
You can use cy.task(setValue) and cy.task(getValue), here an example:
Put it into cypress.config.js or into another file if you have an additional repo with all common functions and utils

```
on("task", {
    setData: newData => {
        data = newData !== null ? { ...data, ...newData } : {};
        return data;
    },
    getData: () => {
        return data;
    },
    cleanData: () => {
        return {};
    },
});
```

After that, you can easily use it in any of your tests:

```
cy.task("setData", { user: { email: customer.email } });
cy.task("getData").then( ({ user: { email } }) => {
        cy.get("emailInput").type(email);
    });
```

Or simplify:

```
cy.get("elementText").invoke("text").then(text => {
    cy.task("setData", { text });
});
cy.task("getData").then( ({ text }) => {
        cy.get("input).type(text);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
get studentCouponValue() {
    return cy.get('h4').then(($span) => {
        const couponValue = $span.innerText;
        cy.log(couponValue);
    })
}
```

Comment: Same issue cy.type() can only accept a string or number. You passed in: [object Object] I need to export const couponValue, I suppose it works only locally